# Easy command line method to determine specific ARM architecture string?

Tags: debian, ubuntu, scripting, architecture, cpu-architecture

I'm trying to write a script which will determine actions based on the architecture of the machine.  I already use `uname -m` to gather the architecture line, however I do not know how many ARM architectures there are, nor do I know whether one is `armhf`, `armel`, or `arm64`.

As this is required for this script to determine whether portions of the script can be run or not, I am trying to find a simple way to determine if the architecture is `armhf`, `armel` or `arm64`.  Is there any one-liner or simple command that can be used to output either `armhf`, `armel`, or `arm64`?

The script is specifically written for Debian and Ubuntu systems, and I am tagging as such with this in mind (it quits automatically if you aren't on one of those distros, but this could be applied in a much wider way as well if the command(s) exist)

---

EDIT: Recently learned that armel is dead, and arm64 software builders (PPA or virtual based) aren't the most stable.  So I have a wildcard search finding `arm*` and assuming armhf, but it's still necessary to figure out a one liner that returns one of the three - whether it's a Ubuntu/Debian command or a kernel call or something.

Comment: Why do you say that "armel is dead" ?

Answer (score 195, accepted):

On Debian and derivatives,

```
dpkg --print-architecture
```

will output the primary architecture of the machine it’s run on. This will be `armhf` on a machine running 32-bit ARM Debian or Ubuntu (or a derivative), `arm64` on a machine running 64-bit ARM.

On RPM-based systems,

```
rpm --eval '%{_arch}'
```

will output the current architecture name (which may be influenced by other parameters, *e.g.* `--target`).

Note that the running architecture may be different from the hardware architecture or even the kernel architecture. It’s possible to run `i386` Debian on a 64-bit Intel or AMD CPU, and I believe it’s possible to run `armhf` on a 64-bit ARM CPU. It’s also possible to have mostly `i386` binaries (so the primary architecture is `i386`) on an `amd64` kernel, or even binaries from an entirely different architecture if it’s supported by QEMU (a common use for this is `debootstrap` chroots used for cross-compiling).

Answer (score 4):

In case dpkg is not installed in your system (for example in lean docker container), this command will helps you

```
$ arch
```